# backtrace not complete stack trace

Tags: c, backtrace

I am reading the `backtrace()` usage in C. There is an official example in Linux man page as shown below.

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
myfunc3(void)
{
    int j, nptrs;
#define SIZE 100
    void *buffer[100];
    char **strings;

    nptrs = backtrace(buffer, SIZE);
    printf("backtrace() returned %d addresses\n", nptrs);

    strings = backtrace_symbols(buffer, nptrs);
    if (strings == NULL) {
        perror("backtrace_symbols");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < nptrs; j++)
        printf("%s\n", strings[j]);

    free(strings);
}

static void   /* "static" means don't export the symbol... */
myfunc2(void)
{
    myfunc3();
}

void
myfunc(int ncalls)
{
    if (ncalls > 1)
        myfunc(ncalls - 1);
    else
        myfunc2();
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s num-calls\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    myfunc(atoi(argv[1]));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output is the following:

```
$ cc -rdynamic prog.c -o prog
$ ./prog 3
backtrace() returned 8 addresses
./prog(myfunc3+0x5c) [0x80487f0]
./prog [0x8048871]
./prog(myfunc+0x21) [0x8048894]
./prog(myfunc+0x1a) [0x804888d]
./prog(myfunc+0x1a) [0x804888d]
./prog(main+0x65) [0x80488fb]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc) [0xb7e38f9c]
./prog [0x8048711]
```

I am curious why there is no `myfunc2` in this backtrace?

Comment: Just guessing - is it possible that the compiler has optimized away the call to `myfunc2` as it does not do any real work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679567/alternative-to-backtrace-on-linux-that-can-find-symbols-for-static-functions

Comment: @bartoli Many thanks.

Comment: `#define SIZE 100` followed by `void *buffer[100];` is scary.